# NextJS getStaticProps is not getting called

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo-client

I am trying to get `getStaticProps` to return some data, but the function is never called. I looked up the official documentation and the examples and also checked various answers here at SO but I still can't get it to work.

The fact that the `console.log` inside the `getStaticProps` never runs leads me to think that there is a configuration error with my code, but I can't find the root cause of the problem.

My apollo client configuration is the following:

[image: apollo client configuration]

The `constants` file that has the ApolloClient options is the following

[image: constants file with apollo configuration]

My component is the following, in the `useEffect` the `console.log` commands logs `undefined` and I never see the `console.log` command from inside the `gerStaticProps` getting called either.

[image: Main component]

I also have a custom `_app` component which is the following:

[image: custom _app component]

My folder structure is the following:

[image: folder structure]

I think there is a good chance the problem lies in my `_app.tsx` component and that [this page from the official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) contains the solution, but even after trying it I did not solve my problem.

Comment: Please provide the code as a snippet, do _not_ use images for code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the info provided, two possible reasons are ,

1. getStaticProps must be used in a page. Check if the file you are using is a page and not a component.
2. The file structure may be causing the issue. Follow this thread [Is this Next.JS folder structure recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854104/is-this-next-js-folder-structure-recommended)

Comment: I think it has something to do with the exports I do in my `index` files. I just created a simple component directly under the `Pages` folder (meaning a tsx file, not a folder containing other files) and it receives values from `getStaticProps`.

Comment: Ok, most probably nextJS is not identifying your 'Main' component as a page. getStaticProps must be called on files in the pages folder and not on components imported from these pages .

Comment: Yeah basically my `/src/pages/index.ts` file was just export my `Main.tsx` component. I made it so it actually renders it and then placed `getStaticProps` in there and it works.